# Shift + t not working

Tags: hardware-failure

Hello I don't know why my  **Laptop Left shift** does not work with some letters like **t** and **y** I mean it **wont**  capital this letters. and sometimes not work in game.

honestly sometimes work correctly and most time does not work correct
I connected another USB  Keyboard and that  was working properly
its really nerve-racking  and boring
how can I find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I connected another USB Keyboard and that was working properly

Your keyboard is defective and you need to get a replacement from the computer manufacturer.

Use the USB Keyboard until you can get a new laptop keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Hello again I'm topic creator. i find my problem by removing **Keycaps** and then using **vacuum cleaner**

**Note**: (first remove F-Keys and space button) and then also all function buttons

**Note 2**:  alcohol can be very good after vacuum cleaner